# Comparison about balanced binary search trees

Tags: data-structures, tree, red-black-tree, avl-tree

I've read some Q&As about self-balancing binary trees, but I'm not quite familiar with all of them.

The first one of them I got to know is AVL, the second is Red-Black tree.

There are something I don't quite understand: according to some books and articles, AVL can perform searching a little bit faster than Red-Black tree, well, this is understandable.

1. Then what's Red-Black tree's edge over AVL?
2. In AVL, probably after each insertion, we have to check for balance, but in Red-Black tree we don't have to do something like that frequently, right?

PS:
I search SO for something similar, but I didn't get satisfying answer.
Hope some friends can give me a detailed comparison of self-balancing trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AVL tree has the following property: from each node, the difference in height of the left and the right subtree is at most 2.

In a red-black tree, on the other hand, the height of the left or right subtree of any node is at most *twice* the height of the other tree. That is, they differ at most by a factor of 2.

This shows intuitively that lookup is indeed faster in an AVL tree on average.

However, when inserting or deleting a node, we have to rebalance the AVL tree more often, to preserve the much stricter height invariant (on the other hand, rebalancing in a red-black tree is algorithmically much more complicated). This means that in practice, a red-black tree may perform much better than an AVL tree, in particular when it’s often changed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Did you mean, the only edge that rb-tree has over AVL is that rb-tree perform less rebalance operation, and it should be convenient if we do updates (insertion/deletion) a lot?

Comment: @Alcott Essentially yes. In practice, rb-trees outperform AVL trees for most purposes. AVL trees perform better in situations where you build the tree *once*, and then only use it for lookup. But in such situations, you don’t need a self-balancing tree at all: since it’s static, it can be manually balanced once.

Comment: I know that B-tree is popular in database stuff, I also read several articles about B-tree's application in database, but I still don't quite understand how the data arranged in the disk and how to keep the B-tree structure in the disk?

Comment: @Alcott => new question. The short answer, though: B-trees have better locality of reference. Everything else is pretty  much the same as for main memory.